# R Code Error - Twitter Scraping

Tags: r, text, analytics, screen-scraping

```
#Get tweets
rose <- userTimeline('therealroseanne',n=3000, maxID=NULL, sinceID=NULL, includeRts=TRUE, excludeReplies=FALSE)

#Convert to dataframe
rose_dataframe = do.call("rbind",lapply(rose,as.data.frame))

#Isolate "text" column
roseTweets = select(rose_dataframe,text)

#Create corpus for conditioning
roseCorpus <- Corpus(DataframeSource(roseTweets))
```

> roseCorpus is creating the error:
>
> Error: all(!is.na(match(c("doc_id", "text"), names(x)))) is not TRUE

I have restarted and reloaded all the packages and libraries several times.

Comment: 1. Tell us the packages you are using. 2. Tell us which of these four commands generates the error.
3. When you get obscure error messages, try `options(error = recover)`.

Comment: For this session I have the following installed: library(twitteR)
library(ROAuth)
library(httr)
library(tau)
library(tm)
library(RCurl)
library(dplyr)   The error comes when ctrl+enter on the variable roseCorpus

Comment: Use Mike Kearney's `rtweet` -- it's the modernized version of `twitteR` and I believe the two authors collaborated on `rtweet`.